# Increase count on each save of file in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating one app in excel for bill generate and save data in other sheet in same excel file.

Now I need to increase value of invoice number in bill. My invoice number is `2016-17/12345` after save of bill and this value should be this `2016-17/12346`.

```
Dim CustomerInvoice As Long
Range("H10").Value = Range("H10") + 1
-
-
CustomerInvoice = Range("H10")
-
-
ActiveCell.Value = CustomerInvoice
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
```

Comment: If you are looking for a VBA solution then there is no need to add `Excel-Formula` tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Range("H10").Value = Split(Range("H10").Value, "/")(0) & _
                     "/" & _
                     Val(Split(Range("H10").Value, "/")(1)) + 1
```

**My Assumption**: The current value of `Range("H10").Value` is `2016-17/12345`

Comment: Perfect Solution.  Thanks... :)

Comment: BTW what should happen on 1 Jan 2018 ;)?

Comment: `Range("H10").Value = Year(Date) - 1 & "-" & Format(Date, "yy") & "/" & Val(Split(Range("H10").Value, "/")(1)) + 1`